# Weird ^M and no correct line breaks in csv file, trying to remove with sed

Tags: bash, file, sed

I am trying to process a bunch of files that were saved in a very weird way.

They start like this:

```
started recording,2016-08-16 15:12:10.661^M
stopped recording,2016-08-16 15:16:29.373^M
item number,16^M
baseline,no^M
item,something^M
item,something^M
item,X             ^Mitem,something                ^Mitem,12,of 14  ^something,10,of 10 ^Mitem,10^Mitem,good
^M
time,item,continue^M
```

Text editor Kate shows the file correctly, but vim doesn't and Python doesn't read it correctly. There should be a line break after item, X and after 14.

I basically need to remove the double tabs between them and replace with a comma and line break. I did that using the code below:

```
#replace double tab by tab
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\t\t/\t/g' {} \;

#replace tab by comma and enter
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i 's/\t/,\n\t/g' {} \;

#remove lines that contain only whitespace
find ./ -type f -exec sed -i sed '/^\s*$/d'{} \;
```

But it's still weird:

```
started recording,2016-08-11 15:08:24.926^M
stopped recording,2016-08-11 15:12:12.671^M
item,10^M
item,no^M
item,something^M
item,something
Condition,X,
        ^Mitem,relax,
        ^Msomething,10,of 14 ^Msomething ^Mitem,10,
        ^Mitem,good^M
time,item,continue^M
```

It basically needs to be a two column csv file. How can I remove the strange behaviour?

--update, after running  sed -i 's/\r//g' filename   it still doesn't split playlist to another line.

```
started recording,2016-08-16 14:56:49.520
stopped recording,2016-08-16 15:03:09.203
item,16
item,no
item,something
item,something
item,X             item,something          something,9,of 14  item,7,of 10 Titem,10item,good

time,item,continue
```

The problem remains with line: item,X             item,something          somethi...

The line breaks still did not come back.

Comment: `dos2unix filename` ???

Comment: The [tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has lots of information on removing DOS line endings from a file.

Comment: How about using `tr`, `tr -cd "[:print:]\n" < input-file > output-file`?

Comment: can you copy paste output of `cat -e filename`?

Comment: cat -e outputs the same as in emacs. The strange this is. On Mac in TextEdit it shows up fine. Also on Linux in Kate. If I press save in Kate, the file reads normal again in emacs (so with line breaks after two columns).

Answer (score 3):

It is CR (Carriage Return), not tab, do:

```
sed -i 's/\r//g' file.txt
```

Or use `dos2unix` which is specifically designed for this:

```
dos2unix file.txt
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't mind the ^M too much (my python script seems to handle that). The problem is with the weird spacing. e.g. Playlist,relax should start on a new line. Even with the two command you gave me it doesn't do that.

Comment: @dorien Do `sed -i 's/\r//g' file.txt`, note the `g` modifier at the end.

Comment: I just tried that, see update in question. It looks better, but the crutial line still isn't split.

Comment: @dorien No, you missed the `g` at the end: `sed -i 's/\r//g'`

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. But still the same (- the ^M)

Comment: @dorien As you can see all `^M`s are gone

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that if I open the original file in Kate, every "something" is displayed on a new line. It isn't if I open it with vim.  It has been driving me crazy for the last 3h.